# xmlstarlet select value based on condition

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

Based on this [link](https://alistairisrael.wordpress.com/2007/09/26/querying-an-xml-document-using-xmlstarlet/), I am trying to solve a similar problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>iwidget</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.9.1b</version>
  <name>iwidget</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I want to extract the `groupId` if `artifactId` is equal to `iwidget`.

What I have tried so far:

```
xmlstarlet sel -N x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 -t -v "/x:project/x:groupId" < pom.xml
```

Above returned the groupId = `foo.bar`, however, I want it to return only if `artifactId` is equal to `iwidget`

```
$VAR='foo.bar'
xmlstarlet sel -N x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 -t -m "//x:project[artifactId="$VAR"]" -v "//x:project/groupId" < pom.xml
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on your first command, you should be able to apply a simple XPath predicate on `project` to filter it by `artifactId` element value :

```
xmlstarlet sel -N x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 -t \
    -v "/x:project[x:artifactId='iwidget']/x:groupId" < pom.xml
```

Regarding the use of variable, you need to wrap it with quotes so that the value will be recognized as string literal by the XPath processor :

```
xmlstarlet sel -N x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 -t \
    -v "/x:project[x:artifactId='$VAR']/x:groupId" < pom.xml
```

Comment: This does not work with the above pom provided. Can I used a shell variable $var instead of 'iwidget' ? However, even without the variable it does not work.

Comment: I updated the XML in your post a bit to make it well-formed. Can you try the command above with that *exact* XML? I tested it here and it worked (xmlstarlet on docker ubuntu 16.04)..

Comment: What I am looking for is using a shell variable ($VAR) inplace of "iwidget". This works when I pass the string directly, while I pass $VAR returns nothing.

Comment: Regarding the use of variable, you need to wrap it with quotes so that the value will be recognized as string literal :  `"/x:project[x:artifactId='$var']/x:groupId"`

Comment: Can I use multiple `-v` to look for multiple conditions ?  If I only want to print the project.artifactId from every pom.xml, can i just use `-v "/x:project/x:artifactId"` ?

Comment: Yes. You can always try :)