# Conditional extraction of XML attributes with xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

I have some XML (say, file *minimal.xml*) that contains error and warning messages in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <messages>
     <message subMessage="RSC-004">RSC-004, ERROR, [File 'OEBPS/Text/pdfMigration.html' could not be decrypted.], epub20_encryption_binary_content.epub</message>
     <message subMessage="RSC-012">RSC-012, ERROR, [Fragment identifier is not defined.], OEBPS/toc.ncx (24-67)</message>
     <message subMessage="RSC-012">RSC-012, ERROR, [Fragment identifier is not defined.], OEBPS/toc.ncx (30-82)</message>
     <message subMessage="RSC-012">RSC-012, ERROR, [Fragment identifier is not defined.], OEBPS/toc.ncx (36-81)</message>
     <message subMessage="RSC-012">RSC-012, ERROR, [Fragment identifier is not defined.], OEBPS/toc.ncx (42-75)</message>
     <message subMessage="RSC-012">RSC-012, ERROR, [Fragment identifier is not defined.], OEBPS/toc.ncx (48-61)</message>
     <message subMessage="HTM-023">HTM-023, WARN, [An invalid XHTML Named Entity was found: '&amp;0;'.], OEBPS/Text/pdfMigration.html (18-199)</message>
     <message subMessage="HTM-023">HTM-023, WARN, [An invalid XHTML Named Entity was found: '&amp;l0xb'.], OEBPS/Text/pdfMigration.html (291-6)</message>
  </messages>
```

I'm looking for a way to extract the *subMessage* attribute value for all *message* elements that represent an ERROR (which can be identified from the presence of ERROR in the *message*  element's text value). I'm using xmlstarlet. After some searching I found [this somewhat similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42826999/1209004), so I adapted that as follows:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/messages[contains(message,"ERROR")]/message/@subMessage' minimal.xml
```

Result:

```
RSC-004
RSC-012
RSC-012
RSC-012
RSC-012
RSC-012
HTM-023
HTM-023
```

This is not what I expected, since these are the *subMessage* values of *all* message elements! As a further test I modified the query to extract only warnings:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/messages[contains(message,"WARN")]/message/@subMessage' minimal.xml
```

In this case the result is empty! I'm fairly new to xmlstarlet and I suspect I'm overlooking something obvious here. Any help greatly appreciated!

BTW some info on the xmlstarlet version I'm using:

> compiled against libxml2 2.9.2, linked with 20903
>   compiled against libxslt 1.1.28, linked with 10128

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/messages/message[contains(.,"ERROR")]/@subMessage' minimal.xml
```

With `/messages[contains(message,"WARN")]` you erroneously tried to check the content of the `messages` element and not of each `message` element.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the predicate to the `message`, like this:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/messages/message[contains(.,'WARN')]/@subMessage" minimal.xml
```

Comment: Brilliant, that fixes it. Thanks!